# Primary Role DB Not Accessible

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I have A Problem In 
Alwayson Configuration - SQL 2012 SP3 
                       -Windows server 2012
                      "FCI+AG" Configuration

Xnode-1  Xnode-2 'FCI' Cluser Name XDB + 
Xnode3 "Read-only Replica NonFailover Asynccommit "  No listener 
All connect to XDB Cluster

> Cluster Policy Role  HealthCheckTimeout 40000 LeaseTimeout       20000
>   FailureConditionLevel 3

Suddenly Primary Replica Xdb Database Not Accessible 
`Unable to access database 'PROD_DB' because its replica role is RESOLVING which does not allow connections. Try the operation again later.`

and

`message    The availability group database "prod_DB" is changing roles from "PRIMARY" to "RESOLVING" because the mirroring session or availability group failed over due to role synchronization. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.`

and Secondary X-node3 Read Only Auot Check  database Running For 5-7 Min 
after Finishing Check Database

Pls. Need to know WHY PRIMARY REPLICA Not Accessible !and Please How TO prevent that occur again ?

Thanks

> Another Log error 
>   AlwaysOn: The local replica of availability group 'X_AG' is going
>   offline because the corresponding resource in the Windows Server
>   Failover Clustering (WSFC) cluster is no longer online. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> The state of the local availability replica in availability group
>   'X_AG' has changed from 'SECONDARY_NORMAL' to 'RESOLVING_NORMAL'. The
>   replica state changed because of either a startup, a failover, a
>   communication issue, or a cluster error. For more information, see the
>   availability group dashboard, SQL Server error log, Windows Server
>   Failover Cluster management console or Windows Server Failover Cluster
>   log.

Comment: Your log indicates that the cluster went offline. Have you checked the Windows Event logs for errors (easier to see cluster related errors in the Failover Cluster Manager tool). Possibly you lost a disk or network resource.

Comment: The reason for the FCI failing will be in the cluster log. This can be generated by using the get-clusterlog cmdlet as part of the failoverclusters module.

Comment: @nic Cluster Working other database on server  (Not in AG) working Fine

Comment: @SeanGallardy i get log file from cluster no other information in the time that problem happen

Comment: It should tell you why it happened, feel free to anonymize the log and put it on pastebin or something so we can see it.